# How to find out if controller should return JSON using wantsJSON

Tags: sails.js

I saw that in sails there is a variable in the request object called `wantsJSON` and in the error pages that gets generated when creating a new project, it shows

```
if (req.wantsJSON) {
    //Do Something
}
```

How does sails decide whether a user wants JSON or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sails decides that from the request. You can find it in [the source code](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/request/qualifiers.js#L24) . I've copied and commented the interesting part for you:

```
// True, if the request has a xhr polling origin. (via socket)
req.wantsJSON = req.xhr;

// True, if the above was false (or null) and the origin not only accepts html.
// See HTTP header field 'Accept'
req.wantsJSON = req.wantsJSON || !req.explicitlyAcceptsHTML;

// True, if everything above was false (or null) and the origins content type 
// is json and the header field 'Accept' is set.
// See HTTP header field 'Content-type'
req.wantsJSON = req.wantsJSON || (req.is('json') && req.get('Accept'));
```